# How can I present a UITabBarController in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I have a story boar set up with a view that has a button. When I click that button I should go to a custom UITabBarController but all that is displayed is an empty Tab Bar.

```
let tabBar = TabViewController()
self.presentViewController(tabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the story board I have set the class of the TabBarController to be a TabViewController. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the TabViewController a storyboard ID in Interface Builder and get access to it via:

```
if let tabViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TheAssignedID") as? TabViewController {
    presentViewController(tabViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The code you're using is just creating a new instance of the TabViewController class. Not accessing the prototype that you've defined in Interface Builder.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot. But I have to add a cast since the return in the first line is of type AnyObject.

Comment: how can i select with view it goes to when it load?